# Files are in listing when running laravel5.3 project in browser

Tags: php, apache2, ubuntu-14.04, laravel-5.3

Hello guys I am new in Laravel framework. I have successfully install Laravel5.3 in ubuntu. After that I create a new project in Laravel through command prompt and it successfully installed. But when I am running this project in the browser like the url:

`http://localhost/project1 or http://localhost/project1/public`
all the files are in listing manner. So how do I start my project in Laravel.

I've also created virtual host file pointing to `public` folder with url `project1.com`. But that also does not help. Can you please provide what configuration I'm missing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `php artisan serve` laravel build in. And you can also use `php -S localhost:8000` php build in web server. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @Kumar for help, I was missing this step to run the laravel.

Answer (score 0):

If you already installed laravel successfully and you should see accessing with `http://localhost/project1/public` with success laravel vienvenida page.
But you can try running the following command `php artisan make:auth`
At the system command prompt inside the folder of your project.